# Regarding Foreign Key in MVC(3.0) Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I am making an application using MVC 3.0 Razor and Code First Entity Framework.
I am wondering how to define primary key and Foreign Key Relation in the Model.
I know how to define Primary Key.using Key attribute.
for example, I define [Key] attribute in the Model Table Class for Primary Key.
But, really don't know how to define Foreign Key for column in class.
Please Help..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a `List<ChildType>` property in the parent class and a `ParentType` property in the parent class.
EF will generate the key automatically.